# Forms in Symfony2 with Propel?

Tags: php, symfony, propel

I can't seem to find any documentation on Symfony2 forms when using Propel ORM. Is this even supported? When I run the console API it lists all propel commands and none of them was `propel:build-forms`. Does this mean Propel ORM for Symfony2 does not support forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms work on the POPO (Plain Old PHP Objects) level. They have nothing to do with the way you're persisting your model.

Answer (score 1):

To be more precise, Propel + Symfony2 Forms work like a charm: http://www.propelorm.org/cookbook/symfony2/mastering-symfony2-forms-with-propel.html